# Javascript and google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, loops

When I'm executing a javascript code in a loop on a google chrome console, every  javascript things on this page do not work because i'm on this loop.
Is there a way to have an infinite loop on my script and to continue to have my web page working fine ?
Do i have to use some kinds of threads ?

Comment: A better description of what you want to do would help. Infinite loops are generally a big problem that lock up resources so I'm sure that's not what you want.

Comment: Do not use an infinite loop.  If you need something done periodically, use `setInterval` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what i was searching for !

Comment: Look that does not even come close to making sense. Try harder next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have multiple JavaScript threads in a browser window.

If you are executing a tight loop, some browsers may either lock up because the JavaScript process freezes the UI, or may detect the loop and kill it. Chrome does this, and so do newer versions of Internet Explorer. If the browser did not intervene and allow the user to kill the script the other methods would be killing the process or restarting the machine. (Tight loop example: `while(2+2!==5);`)

If you want to do things at regular intervals - like animation - use **setInterval** to call a function every so many milliseconds. You can do this in a loop by maintaining a simple loop counter.

Example:

```js
function blink(el) // millenials won't get this
{
    el.blink_visible = !el.blink_visible;
    el.style.visibility = el.blink_visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}

var label = document.getElementById('label');
var delayMs = 500; // delay in milliseconds
setInterval(blink, delayMs, label);
```

```html
<h1 id='label'>Hello World</h1>
```

You can set the milliseconds very low and usually get away with it, but it depends on what you are doing in the function called at each iteration.